# GAS: When writing to a spreadsheet in parallel processing, how can the written rows be written without interfering with each other?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I deployed a web app in GAS and I tried to write data on a spreadsheet with parallel processing.(It's for 6 min limit of GAS)
I used "sheet.appendRow(list);" to write on the spraedsheet. With parallel processing, some data that should be written in a new row are witten in the same row, so I lose some data in the spreadsheet.
How do I fix it?

```
//GAS code
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('webapp');
}

function myFunction(n) {
  let lists=[];
  //any process
  //an example
  list.push([1000+n,2000+n,3000+n]);
  list.push([4000+n,5000+n,6000+n]);
  list.push([7000+n,8000+n,9000+n]);
  writedown(lists);
}

function writedown(list) {
  let sp=SpreadsheetApp.openById("~~~~~~~~~~");    
  let sheet = sp.getSheetByName("~~");
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    sheet.appendRow(list[i]);
  }
}
```

```
//webapp.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="runInParallel()">DO IT !!</button>
    <script>
      const limit = 30;

      function runInParallel() {
        for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
              google.script.run.myFunction(i);
        }
      }      
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I should change the insert code "sheet.appendRow(list);" or the way of parallel processing?

Comment: First, in your showing script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) In order to reduce the process cost, you can modify your script without using your `parallel processing`. But, in your expected result, you want to achieve your goal without modifying this. Is my understanding correct? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded. appendRow is slow used setValues() instead. In client side javascript you are typically limited by the browser as to the number of asynchronous threads you can have.  So possibly you lost some of your data because you tried to use more than the browser will support.  Asynchronous does not imply multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) method is [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability), which means that when a row is written with the method, the values in the row will never get intermixed with values of other rows that are written *the same way*. The function's atomicity used to be documented in the method page but that is no longer the case. Nevertheless, there is no reason to believe that it would not be atomic.

To write *more than one row* in one go so that those rows remain contiguous in the output, use the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function. It uses the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) to ensure that data is written without intermixing.